# How to load a parquet file with a dicimal field into BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, decimal, parquet

We have a table named **parq** store as parquet, and there is a field which is Decimal in **parq**.

When I load **parq** into BigQuery, I got a message :

> "Parquet type 'FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY' (DECIMAL) for field 'field_name' is
>   not supported."

Load result:

> Waiting on bqjob_r70dd180dddb0942d_00000160bb2ff706_1 ... (1s) Current
>   status: DONE Error in query string: Error processing job
>   'project_id:bqjob_r70dd180dddb0942d_00000160bb2ff706_1': Parquet type
>   'FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY' (DECIMAL) for field 'field_name' is not supported.

Command:

```
bq load --source_format=PARQUET --time_partitioning_type=DAY "dataset.table$20171001" "gs://data.0.parq"
```

How can I load parquet file like **data.0.parq** into Bigquery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DECIMAL type is not yet supported by BigQuery. According to Google, should be ready in Q1: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35906014

So meanwhile I guess you would have to Cast this field into a Float before storing it into Parquet